# How can I use msbuild to add a security certificate that I can use in IIS

Tags: security, deployment, iis-7, msbuild, msbuildextensionpack

I have this target

```
<Target Name = "AddLocalCertificate">       
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Security.Certificate TaskAction="Add" FileName="$(CertificateLocation)" CertPassword="$(CertificatePassword)">           
        <Output TaskParameter="Thumbprint" PropertyName="CertificateHash"/>             
    </MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Security.Certificate>
</Target>
```

and in another target this binding statement

```
<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Web.Iis7Binding
  CertificateHash="$(CertificateHash)" 
  TaskAction="Add" MachineName="$(MachineName)" Name="$(SiteName)" BindingInformation="*:$(HttpsPort):$(SiteName)" BindingProtocol="https"/>
```

However when I run the targets I get the error

> Creating binding with certificate: thumb print
>   'DBE4964B4C4D0F185E8B1D421D736390AE586EBF' in stor   e 'MY'
>   C:\Projects\RC19_Release2\ExternalBinaries\MSBuildGlobalFiles\ManageWebsite.targets(154,3):
>   error :  COMException: A specified logon session does not exist. It
>   may already have been terminated. (Exce ption from HRESULT:
>   0x80070520)\r
>   C:\Projects\RC19_Release2\ExternalBinaries\MSBuildGlobalFiles\ManageWebsite.targets(154,3):
>   error :

When I look in IIS it has created the site and the binding is there, but it does not seem to be able to find the certificate, and if I look in the  "Server Certificates" on IIS then I cannot see my certificate.

If I do MMC -> certificate snap in and go to Current User then I can see my cert in there.

How do I either access that certificate from within IIS/msbuild or have msbuild create it in the correct place for IIS to be happy?

The msbuild extension help page is this http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.5.0/html/45763eac-8f14-417d-9b27-425161982ffe.htm but it has not helped me much!

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well I got it working... clearly no one cares but me :D

The substantive change was to add  Exportable="True" MachineStore="True" to the certificate add task like so

```
<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Security.Certificate TaskAction="Add" Exportable="True" MachineStore="True" FileName="$(CertificateLocation)" CertPassword="$(CertificatePassword)">         
        <Output TaskParameter="Thumbprint" PropertyName="CertificateHash"/>             
    </MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Security.Certificate>
```

and all is good in the world once again.